# Can't send Email with SMTP and gmail account on C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I'm trying to send emails for account confirmation, but I get a problem on the SMTP side. [image]

I saw someone had this problem before and they fixed it by enabling "Less secure apps to sign in" but google removed that as a feature.
[image]

EmailSender.cs

```
public bool SendEmail(string userEmail, string confirmationLink)
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("employmentlyy@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(userEmail));

            mailMessage.Subject = "Confirm your email";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = confirmationLink;

            var emailPass = _config["emailPassword"];

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("employmentlyy@gmail.com", emailPass);
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Port = 587;
            

            try
            {
                client.Send(mailMessage);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent email!");
                return true;
            }
            catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
            {
                // log exception
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I tried to change UseDefaultCredentials to false and changing ports but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Did you see the "Important" note in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient)? SmtpClient should no longer be used.

Comment: Did you see this: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: @Flydog57 yes, still not working.

Comment: By the way, it would have been nice to include a link to https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255? (the likely source of your pink box above).  That way, we can read it in context without having to type in the contents of the picture you posted.  You might have also mentioned that you had tried what I had suggested and it didn't help (and show what you had tried)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
public bool SendEmail(string userEmail, string confirmationLink)
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("employmentlyy@gmail.com");
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(userEmail));

    mailMessage.Subject = "Confirm your email";
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mailMessage.Body = confirmationLink;

    var emailPass = _config["emailPassword"];

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("employmentlyy@gmail.com", emailPass);
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.Port = 587;
    client.EnableSsl = true;

    try
    {
        client.Send(mailMessage);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent email!");
        return true;
    }
    catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
    {
        // log exception
    }
    return false;
}
```

client.UseDefaultCredentials = true; is removed as it is not necessary and might cause problems.
client.EnableSsl = true; is moved to after setting the client.Port property.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following piece of code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace EmailApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String SendMailFrom = "Sender Email";
            String SendMailTo = "Reciever Email";
            String SendMailSubject = "Email Subject";
            String SendMailBody = "Email Body";

            try
            {
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
                SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
                // START
                email.From = new MailAddress(SendMailFrom);
                email.To.Add(SendMailTo);
                email.CC.Add(SendMailFrom);
                email.Subject = SendMailSubject;
                email.Body = SendMailBody;
                //END
                SmtpServer.Timeout = 5000;
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SendMailFrom, "Google App Password");
                SmtpServer.Send(email);

                Console.WriteLine("Email Successfully Sent");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials** is set to false, furthermore, you can read the further steps here: https://www.techaeblogs.live/2022/06/how-to-send-email-using-gmail.html